# Propuesta de etiqueta: código-obsoleto

Tags: discusión, etiquetas

Al plantear esta pregunta: [jQuery 3 declaró document.ready obsoleto ¿hay cambios también para window.load?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/92628/29967) quise ponerle la etiqueta `código-obsoleto` o algo parecido.

¿Considerarían útil tener una etiqueta que agrupase las preguntas relativas al tema o existe ya alguna que podría aplicarse a este tipo de preguntas?

Comment: Yo creo que sería interesante tener una etiqueta para estos casos, pero dependería de las temáticas aceptadas en el sitio, la etiqueta que propones se podría usar para solicitar ayuda actualizando un código obsoleto, algo así como la comunidad https://codereview.stackexchange.com/, pero seria interesante tener algo asi.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`código-obsoleto` parece una meta-etiqueta las cuáles deben evitarse de acuerdo a [¿Qué son las etiquetas, y cómo debo usarlas?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Creo que sería mejor usar una etiqueta específica para la versión por ejemplo [jquery-3](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-3)